# Hola todos, he intentado hacer un input en javascript que cuando el usuario seleccione tal opción aparezca el input

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, php7

*codigo html*
estoy intentando llamar el id del select para que cuando el usuario selecione la opcion si, salga tres inputs pero no muestra esos inputs

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                 <label for="">Mouse?</label>
                 <div class="input-group">
                   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-hand-pointer-o"></i> 
                    </span>
                   <select class="form-control input-sm" name="mouse" id="mouse">
                   <option value="1" id="n">No</option>
                   <option value="2" id="s">Si</option>
                   </select>
                 </div>
               <div class="especificaciones"></div>  
               </div>
                  
                </div>
```

*codigo JavaScript*
aquí estoy llamando el id que le di el nombre de mouse, entonces pongo un if si el usuario si cuenta con el objeto entonces que aparezcan los tres inputs en la pagina, realmente no se si este bien lo que hice o algo que me falte

```
$('#mouse').change(function(){

  var raton = $(this).val();

      if(raton == "s"){
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("col-xs-12");
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("col-xs-6");
        $(this).parent().parent().children(".especificaciones").html(

                        '<div class="col-xs-4">'+
                        '<br>'+

                       '<div class="input-group">'+

                       '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="ion ion-social-usd"></i></span>'+

                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_marca"  name="m_marca" placeholder="marca" value="0" >'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-xs-4">'+
                          '<br>'+

                       '<div class="input-group">'+

                       '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>'+

                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_modelo"  name="m_modelo" placeholder="modelo" >'+

                        '</div>'+
                        '</div>' +

                          '<div class="col-xs-4">'+

                            '<br>'+

                       '<div class="input-group">'+

                       '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-sort-numeric-asc"></i></span>'+

                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_serie"  name="m_serie" placeholder="serie" >'+
                       '</div>'+
                          '</div>' )
      }

})
```

*quiero aclarar brevemente que estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y talvez
algunas cosas no tenga sentido, espero contar con su apoyo
estoy abierto a sus comentarios y sugerencias gracias*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola! Me parece que ese código de JQuery que usas es un poco más complicado de lo necesario.

Puedes lograr lo que te propones agregando manejo del evento **onchange** de tu select, de modo que reaccione cada vez que selecciones un valor diferente, el Javascript determine si mostrar o no los inputs.

Con tu permiso, utilizo tu mismo código y te dejo el snippet con algunas adiciones que lo hacen funcional. Sin embargo, donde agrego los input, puede ir cualquier elemento de HTML que desees, y va a funcionar igualmente siempre y cuando la función de JS los llame por su id correcto, así que hay que poner atención a que haya esa correspondencia.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

```js
function mostrarInputs(valor){
    if(valor === "true"){
        //En este caso, se cambia el estilo a display block, si se supone que se muestren
        document. getElementById('input1').style.display="block";
        document. getElementById('input2').style.display="block";
        document. getElementById('input3').style.display="block";
    }
    else{
        //En este caso, se cambia el estilo a display none, si se supone que no se muestren
        document. getElementById('input1').style.display="none";
        document. getElementById('input2').style.display="none";
        document. getElementById('input3').style.display="none";
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label for="">Mouse?</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-hand-pointer-o"></i>
                </span>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" name="mouse" id="mouse" onchange="mostrarInputs(this.value)">
                    <option value="false" id="n">No</option>
                    <option value="true" id="s">Si</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="especificaciones">
                <!--Aquí se agregan 3 input, pero podría ser cualquier elemento HTML-->
                <!--Nótese que uso el atributo style para definir si mostrarles o no,-->
                <!--esto funciona con cualquier elemento HTML-->
                <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Input 1" style="display: none;"/>
                <input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="Input 2" style="display: none;"/>
                <input type="text" id="input3" placeholder="Input 3" style="display: none;"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió demasiado tu explicación

Answer (score 0):

en tu código jQuery te puedes ahorrar muchas líneas de código, si los inputs los metes directo en tu código HTML, y solo muestras u ocultas en base a tu select.

Ejemplo:

```js
$('#mouse').change(function(){

    var raton = $(this).val();

    if(raton == "si") {
        $('.especificaciones').show();    
    } else {
        $('.especificaciones').hide();  
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .especificaciones {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="">Mouse?</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-hand-pointer-o"></i> 
            </span>
            <select class="form-control input-sm" name="mouse" id="mouse">
              <option value="no">No</option>
              <option value="si">Si</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="especificaciones">
            <!-- Agregar los campos que necesitas -->
            <div class="col-xs-4">                      
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="ion ion-social-usd"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_marca"  name="m_marca" placeholder="marca" value="" >
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_modelo"  name="m_modelo" placeholder="modelo" >
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-sort-numeric-asc"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_serie"  name="m_serie" placeholder="serie" >  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.